# Expiring bounties assigned automatically - what now?

Tags: support, bounty

I've recently put a bounty on someone else's question, and unfortunately I was away during the period of time I was given to allocate the bounty. I had an answer in mind, I just failed to "do it" before the deadline as I was travelling and had no time to review all answers and finalise my choice.

The question: [Office 2013 smooth cursor while typing](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/66908/office-2013-smooth-cursor-while-typing)

My bounty was assigned to the most voted answer. Except the most voted answer is a commentary... It's not an answer to the asked question, and it certainly does not give evaluation criteria or relevant research as to how to implement the feature being (rightfully) critiqued.

Is it possible to override this assignment in any way and return the bounty to its intended recipient? Babalwa Mehlomane's answer in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it's not possible to retract a given Bounty, even if its made by the system. Sorry

Comment: Thanks, that's good to know.